# Remote port forwarding with Putty

Tags: port-forwarding, putty

When I create a remote port forwarding tunnel with Putty, a remote port opens on interface with ip `127.0.0.1`. On the remote host I'm able to `nc localhost RPORT` and forwarding works, but I'm unable to connect with `nc RHOST RPORT`. The problem is, that `RPORT` gets open on wrong interface -- localhost, instead of the public IP interface.

How can I setup remote port forwarding, so that I can connect from the internet, to `RHOST:RPORT`?

On `RHOST`, `netstat -an | grep RPORT` returns `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:RPORT         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: I think you are confusing local forwarding with remote forwarding. Setup on your image would forward local port 3128 to a remote port proxy:3128. My problem is with remote -> local.

Answer (score 2):

`GatewayPorts` needs to be set to `on` in sshd_config for the far side to allow others to connect to the forwarded port or you need to check 'Remote ports do the same (SSH-2 only)' in the PuTTY GUI to request that setting of the session.

If you wanted to forward from other hosts via PuTTY you need to check the 'Local ports accept connections from other hosts' setting.